# Can we update a consumer offset in kafka 0.10?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using older version of Kafka, 0.10. Is there any way by which I can update the consumer offset for a topic to an arbitrary number?

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka 0.10, I don't think there was a tool to easily update a consumer offset.

You basically have 2 options:

- Use the tools from a more recent Kafka version. Nowadays, consumer offsets can be updated using both the [`kafka-consumer-groups.sh`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group) tool or the `AdminClient` (only in trunk at the moment, it will be in Kafka 2.5).
- Write a small application that starts a consumer and calls [`commitSync()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.util.Map-) to update its consumer offsets, like in [`ConsumerGroupCommand.resetOffsets()`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L373-L402)